# spring and guava version compatability

Tags: spring, guava

I have spring4.3.10 & Spring Secuity 4.2.3 Guava 12.0 and JDK1.7.; The application is running fine now.
        I have to upgrade the Spring version because of bug annouced by Spring in those versions: [https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-1199][1]
        SO, I am upgrading sping from 4.3.10 to 4.3.16; Spring Security 4.2.3 to 4.2.4. 
        **Now I get this error : import javax.annotation.concurrent.Immutable**;

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gemstone/gemfire/internal/cache/BridgeObserverHolder
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.CacheClientUpdater.processMessages(CacheClientUpdater.java:1692)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.CacheClientUpdater.run(CacheClientUpdater.java:459)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.BridgeObserverHolder
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
        ... 2 more

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gemstone/gemfire/internal/cache/BridgeObserverHolder
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.CacheClientUpdater.processMessages(CacheClientUpdater.java:1692)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.CacheClientUpdater.run(CacheClientUpdater.java:459)
INFO : com.abc.cportal.delivery.publisher.adapters.SearchContentAdapter - Search sender shut down.
Exception in thread "SearchContentAdapter - background runner" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableAsList
        at com.abc.cportal.delivery.search.LocalSearchCache.getRecords(LocalSearchCache.java:43)
        at com.abc.cportal.delivery.publisher.adapters.SearchfeedUpdater.syncFeeds(SearchfeedUpdater.java:58)
        at com.abc.cportal.delivery.publisher.adapters.SearchRecordScheduler.schedule(SearchRecordScheduler.java:59)
        at com.abc.cportal.delivery.publisher.adapters.SearchContentAdapter.backgroundExecute(SearchContentAdapter.java:237)
        at com.abc.cportal.delivery.publisher.adapters.SearchContentAdapter.access$000(SearchContentAdapter.java:42)
        at com.abc.cportal.delivery.publisher.adapters.SearchContentAdapter$1.run(SearchContentAdapter.java:199)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableAsList
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
```

Comment: Can you post complete error log?

Comment: I added the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is misleading. Because the *Spring* configuration file was looking for *log4j* property file which cannot be found. When I added the *log4j* property files, the *Spring* context could inject it in the declared element and went fine now.
thnx.